# on click functions not working with Cordova?

Tags: javascript, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I just started out with Cordova, and already confused why this simple on click event is not working properly? Below is my index.html file. I read somwhere that the background had to be none and that click dosen't work on phones, but to use tap instead. Tap did not make any difference tho.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <!--
        Customize the content security policy in the meta tag below as needed. Add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src to enable inline JavaScript.
        For details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=617521
    -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">

        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Eventia</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).on("click", ".gg2", function () {
                console.log('hello');
                $('.gg2').css('background-color', 'blue');
            });
        </script>

        <div class="gg" style="background: none">
            <div class="gg2">
                hello world
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not related to cordova, put the script before closing the body tag, so can be able to ready the DOM, surround the script with `ready` event

**example**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).on("click", ".gg2", function () {
        console.log('hello');
        $('.gg2').css('background-color', 'blue');
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like inline JS is disabled. Read the comment you pasted on lines 5-6 carefully. Comment out the `Content-Security-Policy` line to verify that's the cause.